# Determining bound of a function

Tags: functions, continuity, upper-lower-bounds

> Given a function $f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
> \frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} & 0 \leq x \leq 4\\
> \\
> 0 & \text{otherwise}
> \end{matrix}\right.$ is it a bounded function?

I first checked the continuity of $f(x)$ at points $0$,$4$. It was discontinuous. However this function can be bound by another function $\frac{1}{2x}$ when $x>1$ and $0$ otherwise. But am confused whether this argument be used to prove that the function is bounded.

Can you please let me know if the approach to the above formulation is correct?

Comment: What happens if $x=0$?

Comment: at $x=0$ i checked the limit of the $f(x)$. It came as $\infty$

Comment: So is $f(x)$ bounded in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No but if we consider another function say $g(x)=\frac{1}{2x} x>1$ and 0 otherwise. It is the upper bound for $f(x)$. So i got confused that $f(x)$ is not bounded in $\mathbb{R}$ but is bounded by $g(x)$

Comment: Your saying $g(x)$ is an upper bound for $f(x)$? Let's look again at $x=0$. We know that by definition $g(0)=0$ and $f(0)\to\infty.$ So is $\infty<0$?

Comment: Sorry my bad i have made a mistake in the calculation. So in the given case the function is discontinuous and not bounded. Can we generalize that every discontinuous function is unbounded?

Comment: No that's of course not always the case. Do you know exactly what discontinuous and bounded functions are? If you only remember it vaguely, it would be helpful if you read the definitions once again. Also for a counterexample take the [Sign function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function). It is discontinuous *and* bounded (by $1$).

Comment: sorry my bad. Got it thanks

Comment: The "piecewise" function $f(x)=1$ if $x \ge 0$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x<0$ is bounded but not continuous (jump discontinuity at $x=0.)

Comment: @coffeemath thank you